# How to send packet data to dialog?

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I made some received tcp packet dialog by pyqt5.
This code are load dialog, call receive tcp packet in qthread.
I want to send packet data to dialog.
How to send?

It's my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import socketserver


class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.rfile.read(28)
            # how to send packet data to dialog?

        except Exception as e:
            print('MyTCPHandler.handle exception error: ', e)


class TestThread(QThread):
    HOST, PORT = '192.168.0.100', 8484

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    def receive_packet(self):
        socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
        server = socketserver.TCPServer((self.HOST, self.PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

    def run(self):
        print('run thread')
        self.receive_packet()


class TestGUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("start thread", self)
        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        vertBox = QVBoxLayout()
        vertBox.addWidget(self.btn1)
        vertBox.addWidget(self.textbox1)
        self.setLayout(vertBox)
        self.setGeometry(700, 500, 300, 100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.threadStart)
        self.show()

        self.th = TestThread(self)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def threadStart(self):
        self.th.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = TestGUI()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the information of a thread you can use `QMetaObject.invokeMethod()`, so it is necessary to pass the GUI, and in this case we take advantage that the parent of the QThread is the GUI.

You can set a new property to pass the GUI to the handler, and from the handler access that property through self.server.

Finally, we implemented a slot that receives the information.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import socketserver


class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.rfile.read(28)
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.server.w, "setData",
                Qt.QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(bytes, data))

        except Exception as e:
            print('MyTCPHandler.handle exception error: ', e)


class TestThread(QThread):
    HOST, PORT = '192.168.0.102', 8000
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def receive_packet(self):
        socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
        server = socketserver.TCPServer((self.HOST, self.PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.w = self.parent()
        server.serve_forever()

    def run(self):
        print('run thread')
        self.receive_packet()


class TestGUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("start thread", self)
        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        vertBox = QVBoxLayout()
        vertBox.addWidget(self.btn1)
        vertBox.addWidget(self.textbox1)
        self.setLayout(vertBox)
        self.setGeometry(700, 500, 300, 100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.threadStart)
        self.show()

        self.th = TestThread(self)

    @pyqtSlot(bytes)
    def setData(self, data):
        print(data)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def threadStart(self):
        self.th.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = TestGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**@Plus: with signals**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import socketserver


class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.rfile.read(28)
            self.server.qthread.dataChanged.emit(data)

        except Exception as e:
            print('MyTCPHandler.handle exception error: ', e)


class TestThread(QThread):
    HOST, PORT = '192.168.0.102', 8000
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(bytes)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def receive_packet(self):
        socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
        server = socketserver.TCPServer((self.HOST, self.PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.qthread = self
        server.serve_forever()

    def run(self):
        print('run thread')
        self.receive_packet()


class TestGUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("start thread", self)
        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        vertBox = QVBoxLayout()
        vertBox.addWidget(self.btn1)
        vertBox.addWidget(self.textbox1)
        self.setLayout(vertBox)
        self.setGeometry(700, 500, 300, 100)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.threadStart)
        self.show()

        self.th = TestThread(self)
        self.th.dataChanged.connect(self.setData)

    @pyqtSlot(bytes)
    def setData(self, data):
        print(data)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def threadStart(self):
        self.th.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = TestGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks! eyllanesc. your modified code was work! thanks!!

Comment: @SUNGHOLEE If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: Now, I know about `QMetaObject.invokeMethod()` by your guide. no other way?

Comment: you could also use signals.

Comment: possible to signal in `class MyTCPHandler` ?

Comment: no, only the classes that inherit from QObject can have signals, in your case it could be TestThread.

Comment: i want to send received packet data to dialog.
but it's possible in inherit `QObject`.
so I can't send data in `class MyTCPHandler` to dialog?

Comment: The solution that I have proposed does not do that?

Comment: Your proposed was do nicely! You said to me another way about signal. I thought signal implementation is better easy. So I want to know how to implement it.

Comment: Both are simple, deep down they are the same. I do not know what you mean easily, you should indicate to me what you qualify as easy, why is my solution difficult? See my update answer

Comment: Your Answer was too help to me and nice! Just, I learned PyQt now so I want to know more Implement method.

Comment: before searching for the easy, search for the stable and robust.

Comment: ok. I will try more learn python and pyqt. thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks!! Thanks!! eyllanesc!!!!! I saw plus code now.!!! Thank you so much!!!! your are my ANGEL!!!! :D